# How to improve select with not in on firebird

Tags: sql, select, firebird, notin

```
select mid from aplicacao
where mid not in
(
select distinct mid from aplicacao
inner join prod_app on prod_app.mid=aplicacao.mid
where prod_app.coditem=1
)
```

I try to search for a solution on firebird to improve this query but unfortunatelly didn´t have success. Please could someone help me?

Comment: Simplify your table structure and add it to your question. That way someone can help you solve your problem instead of having to guess.

Answer (score 5):

The most common solution for `IN` (and `NOT IN`) performance problems is to use `EXISTS` (or `NOT EXISTS`) instead:

```
select mid from aplicacao
where not exists (
  select 1 from prod_app
  where prod_app.mid = aplicacao.mid and prod_app.coditem=1
)
```

Another solution is to use a `LEFT JOIN` and filter on non-existence of the right side:

```
select mid from aplicacao
left join prod_app
  on prod_app.mid = aplicacao.mid and prod_app.coditem=1
where prod.app.coditem is null
```

Note that additional filter conditions on `prod_app` (like `prod_app.coditem=1`) need to be part of the join condition, not of the `where` clause.

Comment: Look out! Query inside "where not exists()" will be fully executed so many times, as there is records in first query. May take long time to complete.

Comment: @Andrei Yes, but it is still decidedly cheaper than using `IN` (or `NOT IN`), especially because an index can be used.

Comment: May-be. But right now i am waiting for for my colleague to come and restart firebird on test server, where i ran "where not exists" on two large queries :) "left join" may be safer in that matter, i think.

Comment: @Andrei you can also delete the statement from `mon$statements` to cancel it. Also if it takes very long, that might be a sign of using an unrelated subquery, or absence of relevant indexes.